# Whe Nodejs can not find module by existing path?

Tags: node.js, typescript

How to fix error `Unable to import main.handler module. Error: Cannot find module '/function/code/skill/index' imported from /function/code/main.js`. Stack: Nodejs 18, TypeScript 5.3.3. In typescript no error with import.

```
// main.js
import { MainScenario } from "./skill/index";
export async function handler(request, context) {
    // ...
}
```

```
// skill/index.js
export * from "./Scenario";
```

```
// Scenario.js
export const MainScenario = {
    // ...
}
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.11.19",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
}
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "lib": ["es2022"],
    "module": "ES2022",
    "rootDir": "src",  
    "moduleResolution": "Node", 
    "resolveJsonModule": false, 
    "allowJs": true, 
    "outDir": "build",  
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true,                 
    "noImplicitAny": true,                        
    "skipLibCheck": true                         
  }
}
```

Comment: When targeting ESM in typescript, you have to write ".js" extension in import statement (yes, js, not ts, even in ts file). This is very unintuitive but it is how it is. You can read some discussion in [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42151)

Answer (score 2):

Add extension to this import ".js"

from

```
export * from "./Scenario";
```

to

```
export * from "./Scenario.js"
```

The same for ./skill/index.js

[image]